# How to update Yeoman dependencies?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yeoman, bower

Every yeoman generator has its package.json and bower.json that contain the dependencies.
When I initialize a new project with:

```
yo somegenerator
```

it starts to download and install the dependencies, according to the version saved in the files.

#### My question is: how can I update the dependencies when I initialize a new project?

I would that when I type "yo somegenerator", it  download the latest dependencies and update the files (package.json and bower.json) with the current version.

Answer (score 2):

Generators are designed with particular dependency version requirements intentionally. You are free to experiment with upgrading these dependencies, of course-- it's your app after all! Your question isn't really "how can Yeoman" update my dependencies, but "how can I update my dependencies?" Just wanted to clear that up.

Depending on what you want to upgrade-- jQuery? A grunt plugin? You will have to determine what it is you wish to upgrade, and run the update command for that dependency. See the Bower and npm docs for those commands.

If your generator hasn't been updated in a while, you are free to do so! Remember, generators are simply node modules, distributed via npm.

If you have yo 1.0rc1 or greater installed, you can also type just "yo" to see your installed generators, as well as select the "update your generators" option.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Yes, I know npm update --save for update the dependecies and the package.json file...but I must type it separately because yeoman can't do that...right?

Answer (score 0):

As yeoman generators are installed through npm does it not make sense to run

```
npm update somegenerator
```

Alternatively you could do `npm unbuild somegenerator@version` and reinstall.

Comment: I can't do that with my generators